# Lua local table module - multiple instances

Tags: lua

If I created a module in Lua like so:

```
    local numbers = {}
    numbers.a = 1
    numbers.b = 1
    function numbers.change(a, b)
        self.a, self.b = a, b
    end
    return numbers
```

Can I require this module multiple times to get different instances of it?

```
    set1 = require "numbers"
    set2 = require "numbers"
```

Do both set1 and set2 reference the same numbers table?

How does one elegantly go about making this work?

Comment: Can't you just ask the lua interpreter with `print(set1 == set2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` explicitly loads modules only once. If you want multiple instances, call `dofile` instead. Or call `loadfile` once, save the result, and call it multiple times.